# Which process is making a particular connection

Tags: networking, process, ip

I'm using `iftop` to see what connections are being made from my machine.
I see this one strange connection to a remote server that I don't know and I don't know why that connection is being made.

```
me               => unknown.domain.com    0b    638b    638b
                 <=                       0b    754b    764b
me               => gateway               0b    179b    179b
                 <=                       0b    205b    205b
239.255.255.250  => local-machine         0b      0b      0b
                 <=                       0b      0b   1.61Kb
```

How can I find out what process is making the connection with `unknown.domain.com`?

Answer (score 5):

```
netstat -ap
```

An example of the output...

```
[me@util tmp]$ netstat -ap |more
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 util:34782              unknown.domain.com:http ESTABLISHED 15273/firefox
```

The above output is abbreviated to highlight a single example.  Your actual output will very likely be much longer.

=== EDIT ===
An alternative to using `netstat` is...

```
ss -tp
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not find the nifty **netstat -ap** functionality on OS/X (10.11.6, El Capitan). You can get the same information using **lsof** on OS/X, and lsof has an additional advantage that it is available for all Unix-like platforms.

```
$ lsof | grep dropbox.com
Dropbox 659 quentin 21u  IPv4 0x3704bf24379 0t0  TCP 10.15.1.6:49609->client.v.dropbox.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Lsof does much more than this. Thanks to Vic Abell for this excellent tool!

ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof.tar.bz2

Comment: On OSX `netstat`'s `p` switch is not the same as on Linux.  On Linux it displays PID/Program name for sockets whereas on OSX is for protocol (I think -- I don't use OSX much).  I don't know that `ss` is available on OSX either.  But given that poster mentioned `iftop` I'm guessing he is not on OSX since, maybe I'm wrong, I don't think iftop is on OSX either.